# Updating minion roles from master server

Tags: salt-stack

Is it possible to update minion roles on-the-fly via master server call without manual ssh'ing to minion server and changing config files? If the answer is 'yes', how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can define role on minion via module [`grains.setval`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.grains.html#salt.modules.grains.setval) (there are also setvals, delval)

```
salt 'myMinionId' grains.setval roles [db, roleB]
```

Comment: Nope, i've tried it (as well as append). Following `.get` calls won't return new value, state.apply won't apply states to new roles.

Comment: which salt version are you using"

Comment: 2015.8.3, vagrant autoinstall

Comment: Try with destructive option, like :
`salt minion grains.setval foo "{'sub-key': 'val', 'sub-key2': 'val2'}"  destructive=True`